Problema con movimiento de mouse en c#
hola estaba viendo un video y supuestamento con este script me funcionaba el movimiento del personaje con el mouse pero cuando hago clic el personaje va lento y se va al lado contrario alguien sabe porque???
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoverConMouse : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float velocidad = 5f;

    private Vector3 posicionObjetivo;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        posicionObjetivo = this.transform.position;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            posicionObjetivo = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            posicionObjetivo.z = this.transform.position.z;
        }
        this.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(this.transform.position, 
posicionObjetivo, velocidad * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}

